# Storing median of a data set and using it for doing calculation

Tags: sas

I have a data set x=(1,4,7,8,10,...................) which has these random values. I want to find the median of the data set and then store it in a call symput so that i can use to find the difference of each of the observation from the median.

what is the function to find the median of this data set by just mentioning the variable name?

I want the data in the below format:

```
X  X-median
1  1-median
4  4-median
7  7-median
8  8-median
10  10-median
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use it in a macro variable.  Just combine it as a dataset.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class noprint;
  var age;
  output out=age_median median(age)=age_median;
run;

data class_fin;
  if _n_=1 then set age_median(keep=age_median);
  set sashelp.class;
  age_minus_median = age - age_median;
run;
```

When you set a dataset this way (a one row dataset with `if _n_=1`) you get its value(s) copied onto every row on the dataset, sort of like if you merged it with some universal by value.

Comment: Thanks for the code. The first part ran well! But the second part created some issued so I used a call symput to save the median vale and then applied it to the final step.

Comment: @user6037890 you don't want to get in the habit of using macro variables to store data.   Using a conditional set is the proper way as you where shown.  You should figure out "some issued" and and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done in PROC SQL;

Let's say you have the x values in table A and create a new table B:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE B AS SELECT x,median(x) AS median,x-median(x) AS offset FROM A;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Only as of SAS 9.4. Before that the median function did not work as expected within proc SQL.